# How to write query to update multiple fields in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

How to write query to update multiple fields in MongoDB?

```
db.product.update(
    {"fileInfo":"undefined"},
    {$unset:{"fileInfo" : "undefined"}},
    {multi:true}
)
```

I want to update a set of documents in product collection. First of all, I need to check if that document `fileInfo` field is undefined. If it is undefined then remove that field.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match against a real BSON `undefined`, and not the string `"undefined"`, you can use the [$type](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator with a value of 6:

```
db.product.update(
    {"fileInfo": {$type: 6}},
    {$unset: {"fileInfo" : ""}},
    {multi:true}
);
```

This is deprecated however, but still works as of MongoDB 3.2.

Comment: Actually in my document fileInfo:"undefined " is there thats why i am using that .I need a initially to find and and then update i herad about findandmodify but i cant use it.. And in waht is $type:6

Comment: [update()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) is what you need, not [findAndModify()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify) as you want to update more than one document. What your document contains is not very clear, you should add a copy of it in the question. And `$type: 6` matches a field based on the type of its value, `6` being the code for `undefined`. Check the docs linked in my answer.